# Import a Scala library with the jvmr Scala interpreter in R

Tags: java, r, scala

I'm experimenting [the jvmr package](http://dahl.byu.edu/software/jvmr/) to run Scala from R. I'm not able to import a library from a local file.

For example, that works for the `java.io._` library :

```
a <- scalaInterpreter()
a['import java.io._']
```

but I don't know where it finds this library.

Now in order to import a jar library from a local folder, I have tried to set the class path using these two ways but none works :

1- set the current directory of Scala (through the Scala interpreter) to the library folder

2- add the path of the library in the `java.class.path` system variable of Scala, as follows:

```
java.class.path <- a['System.getProperty("java.class.path")']
java.class.path <- paste0("pathtomyjar:", java.class.path)
a['val jcpath="${1}"', java.class.path]
a['System.setProperty("java.class.path", jcpath)']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running

```
a <- scalaInterpreter("pathtomyjar.jar")
```

in R is similar to

```
scala -classpath pathtomyjar.jar
```

and that's the way to go.

To add several jars, use a vector in R :

```
a <- scalaInterpreter(c("pathtomyjar1.jar","pathtomyjar2.jar"))
```

is similar to

```
scala -classpath pathtomyjar1.jar:pathtomyjar2.jar
```